# rails-geocoder environmental problem in Rails 3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working with [Alex Reisner's geocoder gem](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) on a Rails 3 app (3.0.3)  because I'm concerned about GeoKit's shakey Rails 3 compatibility.  Alex's gem looked perfect for my application so I started using it and had it working flawlessly last night on my Macbook.  I pushed the app to Github when I got it running.

Today, I did a git clone of the app on a desktop Mac.  Same version of Ruby, Rails and identical source and Gemfile.  This time geocoder is throwing this exception:

```
NameError (uninitialized constant Geocoder::Net):
  app/controllers/restaurants_controller.rb:16:in `create'
```

My models use `after_validation :fetch_coordinates` to geocode the model upon save.

Has anyone noticed any other dependencies outside the bundle that could cause this?  I like the way Alex put this one together but may give geokit-rails3 a try even though it's an unfinished port.

Comment: I intsalled RVM on the problem machine.  All other machines are running Ruby 1.8.7 p330.  Now this one is running 1.8.7 p330 and 1.9.2 p136.  With 1.9.2 it works fine.  With 1.8.7 it has the above error.

Comment: I'm trying to fix this but can't duplicate the problem. Could you try adding "::" at the beginning of line 336 in `lib/geocoder.rb`, so the line becomes: `::Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url)).body` If you can confirm that that solves the problem I'll commit the change.

Answer (score 1):

I just released gem version 0.9.7 which should solve this problem.

Comment: Ok, I just tested with 0.9.8 and it worked fine with my problem environment.  Sorry for the delay in responding...my computer had been re-purposed and wasn't avaialble.  The problem was extremely environmental and did not manifest on any other machine.  Alex...looks solid and many thanks.